# Application to recognize text in PDF files and images(OCR) for Windows

Tags: windows, pdf, images, ocr

**The problem:** PDF files and images from a scanned paper document contain text that cannot be copied or edited. However, manual typing is not possible due to the size of the document and the high time involved.

I'm looking for an app to extract text from pdf and image files for windows.

Preferably,

- lightweight and simple to use
- Recognize text in PDF and image files the easy way
- Text can be saved in a new editable PDF or RTF document
- Open Source or Premium

Comment: Not for Windows but perhaps give 2 Apps for Android a try: Abby TextGrabber (1€/month) or TextFairy (free). they have limitations and the error rate is high, in particular when you take low-quality  photographs  . But still worth investigating because everyone has a high-end smartphone these days.

Answer (score 0):

The company I work for has a document-conversion product called [LEADTOOLS ePrint Professional](https://www.eprintdriver.com/Products/ePrint-Professional) that runs under Windows and includes OCR features.

You can either open an image using the ePrint Workstation application or print to the ePrint printer from any Windows application, perform OCR, then save the result as [text, PDF, RTF or many other formats](https://www.eprintdriver.com/Features/Formats).

There’s a free evaluation edition you can try to test the OCR result quality before you decide to purchase. You can obtain it [from this page](https://www.eprintdriver.com/Download).
There’s also free email support during the evaluation period, and if you decide not to purchase, you can simply un-install the program.